# Excel files sheet recover which deleted from excel file

Tags: excel-2013

I have a excel file which have more then 5 sheet in this files.
Unintentionally i have deleted one of sheet from this excel file and save this file.
How can i recover this sheet of this file?

Please suggest me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restore the previous version from your backup.

If the file is stored in OneDrive for Business, OneDrive or SharePoint online, restore the previous version from the version history.

If you don't have a backup or if you don't store the file online, then the sheet deletion cannot be reversed.

You will need to re-create the deleted sheet from scratch.

Take it as a learning exercise and implement backup or versioning, so this does not happen again.

Comment: is there any way to restore deleted sheet using any data recovery tool? can you suggest any specific tool for this purpose?it's an important file with some official transaction data, so it's badly needed.

Comment: No. Read my post again. If you don't make provisions to recover files, you won't be able to recover files. It's really simple. And the rules don't change, just because the file you stuffed up is important. Even important files (or ESPECIALLY important files) require provisions for backup and recovery. If you don't care to set these up, please don't complain if you lose your work

Comment: Ok. understand. :(

Comment: actually our HR supervisor did it and asking me to restore the file as it is. I have checked all the possible ways, but no luck. I learned this lesson, thanks a lot for your information.

Comment: Learn another lesson: HR don't understand how computers work. Don't let them determine anything related to technology.